# Apache POI SXSSF Shows NullPointerException on flush rows

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-poi, sxssf

I have 500 rows in my table. When I'm using `setRandomAccessWindowSize(1000)` it's working fine. Data is exported successfully in Excel file from resultset, But when I use `setRandomAccessWindowSize(100)` it is giving me a
***NullPointerException*** I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Please suggest proper way to do this.

Here's my code:

```
workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(100);      //SXSSF workbook
workbook.setCompressTempFiles(true);
SXSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet1");     //Generating Excel file
SXSSFRow row;
SXSSFCell cell;
CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
Font font = workbook.createFont();//Create font
font.setBold(true);//Make font bold
style.setFont(font);//set it to bold

int y = 1;
if (rs.isBeforeFirst() == true) {
    while (rs.next()) {
        row = spreadsheet.createRow(0);
        cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue("SR NO");
        cell.setCellStyle(style);
        for (int s = 1; s <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); s++) {
            cell = row.createCell(s);
            cell.setCellValue(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(+s).toUpperCase());
            cell.setCellStyle(style);
        }
        row = spreadsheet.createRow(y);
        cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue(y + "");
        //spreadsheet.autoSizeColumn(0);
        for (int x = 1; x <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); x++) {
            cell = row.createCell(x);
            String address = new CellReference(cell).formatAsString();
            cell.setCellValue(address);
            cell.setCellValue(rs.getString(+x));
            //spreadsheet.autoSizeColumn(x);
        }
        y++;
    }

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(destination));
    workbook.write(out);
    out.close();
    workbook.dispose();
```

Comment: I have used turnery operator which will change null values to empty string but not work for me

Comment: Why are you creating the row 0 having the headers over and over again together with each data row? That's the problem because when reaching data row 101 the row 0 is flushed to disk already and cannot be created again. Do creating row 0 only once outside the `while` loop which creates the data rows.

Comment: Please add the stack trace to the question.

Comment: @AxelRichter Thanks for the help it's working now. It was writing 0 number row multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated while loop in above code. It was writing 0th row multiple times. That's why on 101th row it was giving NullPointer exception as 0th row is already flushed.

Here's my fix-

```
if (rs.isBeforeFirst() == true) {
    while (rs.next()) {
        //writing columns
        if (rs.isFirst()) {
            row = spreadsheet.createRow(0);
            cell = row.createCell(0);
            cell.setCellValue("SR NO");
            cell.setCellStyle(style);
            for (int s = 1; s <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); s++) {
                cell = row.createCell(s);
                cell.setCellValue(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(+s).toUpperCase());
                cell.setCellStyle(style);
            }
        }
        //Writing data
        row = spreadsheet.createRow(y);
        cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue(y + "");
        //spreadsheet.autoSizeColumn(0);
        for (int x = 1; x <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); x++) {
            cell = row.createCell(x);
            cell.setCellValue(rs.getString(+x));
            //spreadsheet.autoSizeColumn(x);
        }
        y++;
    }

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(destination));
    workbook.write(out);
    out.close();
    workbook.dispose();
```